# Creating more than one value for logged-in-timeout in Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, session-timeout, authlogic

My goal is to timeout an admin session after 60 minutes and leave a normal user to timeout after 5 days. I have a User model that is authenticated using Authlogic. The users table has a column named 'role' that accepts a string.

```
  t.string   "role"
```

When the user is admin, role will contain the string 'admin'. I thought about extending `logged_in_timeout`, but haven't figured out how to make that work. The other approach I've looked at is creating multiple sessions and making the :admin session timeout sooner, but once again... not sure how to make that a reality since both sessions would refer to the same user model. Here is what I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |config|
    config.login_field = :email
    config.logged_in_timeout = 5.days
  end
end
```

Session model:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  logout_on_timeout true

end
```

The UserSessionsController is standard, with new create and destroy methods.
Any insights would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found. I did extend the definition of `logged_in_timeout` from authlogic to use this new logic. I did so in the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |config|
    config.login_field = :email
    config.logged_in_timeout = 5.days
  end

  <...>

  def logged_in_timeout
    if self.role == 'admin'
      60.minutes
    else
      self.class.logged_in_timeout
    end
  end
end
```